# Use of MozBackup for back-up Thunderbird data

Tags: thunderbird

Does anyone have any experience with [MozBackup](http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/)? Is it still updated? The News section speaks about the latest release with date December 13th, 2009

I want to back-up my Thunderbird e-mail messages.

Comment: Not quite dead, I see 1.5 alpha 1 was released on 24 July 2010.

Comment: Just transported a Thunderbird profile from one computer (version 3.1.7 English) to another computer (version 3.1.5 Dutch) and it al works fine! E-mail accounts and thousands of e-mail messages, no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, yes it is: http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/